# How can I disable all stack exhange sites except stackoverflow.com?

Tags: internet, productivity

How can I set [SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com/) to only accept visits to stackoverflow.com, but none of the other sites on the stack exchange network? I want to become more productive, but the clickbait with abusive bosses, dumb coworkers and D&D rules are all too enticing...

Comment: try adding stackoverflow to the whitelist & the others to the blacklist

Comment: I did not know you could use both; will try. Listing all sites will be a lot of work though, so other suggestions very welcome.

Comment: I have the list at home, maybe if you remind me I can give it to you :) also there are 173 or so sites but only a few are not subdominans of stackexchange.com

Comment: I use Adblock to hide the list of "hot topics" for a number of SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the list of all Stack Exchange sites (wow this was hard to do on my phone...):

```
http://stackoverflow.com
http://serverfault.com
http://superuser.com
http://meta.stackexchange.com
http://webapps.stackexchange.com
http://gaming.stackexchange.com
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com
http://cooking.stackexchange.com
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com
http://photo.stackexchange.com
http://stats.stackexchange.com
http://math.stackexchange.com
http://diy.stackexchange.com
http://gis.stackexchange.com
http://tex.stackexchange.com
http://askubuntu.com
http://money.stackexchange.com
http://english.stackexchange.com
http://stackapps.com
http://ux.stackexchange.com
http://unix.stackexchange.com
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com
http://apple.stackexchange.com
http://rpg.stackexchange.com
http://bicycles.stackexchange.com
http://programmers.stackexchange.com
http://electronics.stackexchange.com
http://android.stackexchange.com
http://boardgames.stackexchange.com
http://physics.stackexchange.com
http://homebrew.stackexchange.com
http://security.stackexchange.com
http://writers.stackexchange.com
http://video.stackexchange.com
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com
http://dba.stackexchange.com
http://scifi.stackexchange.com
http://codereview.stackexchange.com
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com
http://quant.stackexchange.com
http://pm.stackexchange.com
http://skeptics.stackexchange.com
http://fitness.stackexchange.com
http://drupal.stackexchange.com
http://mechanics.stackexchange.com
http://parenting.stackexchange.com
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com
http://music.stackexchange.com
http://sqa.stackexchange.com
http://judaism.stackexchange.com
http://german.stackexchange.com
http://japanese.stackexchange.com
http://philosophy.stackexchange.com
http://gardening.stackexchange.com
http://travel.stackexchange.com
http://productivity.stackexchange.com
http://crypto.stackexchange.com
http://dsp.stackexchange.com
http://french.stackexchange.com
http://christianity.stackexchange.com
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com
http://linguistics.stackexchange.com
http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com
http://history.stackexchange.com
http://bricks.stackexchange.com
http://spanish.stackexchange.com
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com
http://movies.stackexchange.com
http://chinese.stackexchange.com
http://biology.stackexchange.com
http://poker.stackexchange.com
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com
http://cogsci.stackexchange.com
http://outdoors.stackexchange.com
http://martialarts.stackexchange.com
http://sports.stackexchange.com
http://academia.stackexchange.com
http://cs.stackexchange.com
http://workplace.stackexchange.com
http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com
http://chemistry.stackexchange.com
http://chess.stackexchange.com
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com
http://russian.stackexchange.com
http://islam.stackexchange.com
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com
http://patents.stackexchange.com
http://genealogy.stackexchange.com
http://robotics.stackexchange.com
http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com
http://politics.stackexchange.com
http://anime.stackexchange.com
http://magento.stackexchange.com
http://ell.stackexchange.com
http://sustainability.stackexchange.com
http://tridion.stackexchange.com
http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com
http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com
http://opendata.stackexchange.com
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com
http://blender.stackexchange.com
http://mathoverflow.net
http://space.stackexchange.com
http://sound.stackexchange.com
http://astronomy.stackexchange.com
http://tor.stackexchange.com
http://pets.stackexchange.com
http://ham.stackexchange.com
http://italian.stackexchange.com
http://pt.stackoverflow.com
http://aviation.stackexchange.com
http://ebooks.stackexchange.com
http://beer.stackexchange.com
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
http://arduino.stackexchange.com
http://expatriates.stackexchange.com
http://matheducators.stackexchange.com
http://earthscience.stackexchange.com
http://joomla.stackexchange.com
http://datascience.stackexchange.com
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com
http://buddhism.stackexchange.com
http://hinduism.stackexchange.com
http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com
http://startups.stackexchange.com
http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com
http://ja.stackoverflow.com
http://emacs.stackexchange.com
http://hsm.stackexchange.com
http://economics.stackexchange.com
http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com
http://engineering.stackexchange.com
http://coffee.stackexchange.com
http://vi.stackexchange.com
```

You can also hide the Hot Questions sidebar with a browser extension like AdBlock or Stylish.

Comment: Many thanks. Can't seem to see a way to use the whitelist and blacklist and the same time though, but it I am certain this will help others. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you have to. Just paste all but the top one into your blacklist.

Comment: But I want to disable the whole internet, except SO. But I guess I can't do it without delivering a pull request so I'll accept this until someone else finds a way to do exactly what I want.